# Trying to do Automatic image slider in a fragment in kotlin, However runouithread is not working.Any possible solutions?

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, androidimageslider

I'm trying to do Automatic image slider in fragment in kotlin.
I am trying to convert an activity to fragment. However runouithread is not working in fragments.Any possible solutions??

I tried couple of other things also. But not a possible solution, I can do image slide inside the fragment but not to dod the auomatic sliding....

My mainactivity()

```
package com.example.sliderimagemovie

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <fragment
            android:layout_width="409dp"
            android:layout_height="290dp"
            android:name="com.example.sliderimagemovie.HomeFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="441dp"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

slide_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="275dp">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:id="@+id/slide_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play_button"
            android:id="@+id/glide_play_button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/slide_image" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/slide_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/slide_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/slide_image" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/gradient_bg"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/movie_title" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/glide_play_button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp" android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp" android:textSize="24sp" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".HomeFragment">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="275dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/view_pager_glide"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/indicator_item"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                android:layout_width="395dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_pager_glide" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:id="@+id/indicator">


        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

slide.kt

```
package com.example.sliderimagemovie.Model

class Slide(var image:Int, var title:String)
```

slidePagerAdapater.kt

```
package com.example.sliderimagemovie.Adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import com.example.sliderimagemovie.Model.Slide
import com.example.sliderimagemovie.R

class SlidePagerAdapter:PagerAdapter {


    var mContext: Context?=null
    var mList:List<Slide>?=null

    constructor(context: Context, list:List<Slide>)
    {
        mContext=context
        mList=list
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {

        var inflater:LayoutInflater= mContext!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

        var slideLayout:View =inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_item,null)

        var slideImage:ImageView =slideLayout.findViewById(R.id.slide_image)
        var slideText:TextView=slideLayout.findViewById(R.id.movie_title)
        slideImage.setImageResource(mList!!.get(position).image)
        slideText.setText(mList!!.get(position).title)
        container.addView(slideLayout)

        //return super.instantiateItem(container, position)
        return slideLayout

    }

    override fun isViewFromObject(p0: View, p1: Any): Boolean {
        return p0 == p1
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
    return mList!!.count()
    }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        //super.destroyItem(container, position, `object`)
        container.removeView(`object` as View)
    }
}
```

HomeFragment.kt

```
package com.example.sliderimagemovie
import android.app.Application
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.example.sliderimagemovie.Adapter.SlidePagerAdapter
import com.example.sliderimagemovie.Model.Slide
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*
import kotlin.concurrent.fixedRateTimer

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    var lstSlides:MutableList<Slide> =ArrayList()
    var sliderPage: ViewPager?=null


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        sliderPage=view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_glide)




        lstSlides.add(Slide(R.drawable.spiderman,"Slide1 Spiderman"))
        lstSlides.add(Slide(R.drawable.avenger,"Slide2 Avenger"))
        lstSlides.add(Slide(R.drawable.frozen2,"Slide3 Frozen2"))
        lstSlides.add(Slide(R.drawable.fastfurious,"Slide4 Fastfurious"))
        lstSlides.add(Slide(R.drawable.joker,"Slide5 Joker"))
        lstSlides.add(Slide(R.drawable.jumanji,"Slide6 Jumanji"))
        lstSlides.add(Slide(R.drawable.terminator,"Slide7 Terminator"))



        var adapter: SlidePagerAdapter = SlidePagerAdapter(context!!,this.lstSlides)
        sliderPage!!.adapter=adapter


       indicator.setupWithViewPager(sliderPage,true)
     fixedRateTimer(name = "timer",initialDelay = 4000,period = 6000){

// I'm getting error over here. Since runOnUiThread wont work with fragment , I tried to run with //activity. but its not working. I tried couple of other things.

        getactivity().runOnUiThread
 {
             public override fun run() {
                 if (sliderPage!!.currentItem < lstSlides.count() - 1) {
                     sliderPage!!.currentItem = sliderPage!!.currentItem + 1
                 } else {
                     sliderPage!!.currentItem = 0
                 }

             }
         })

    }
        return view
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean not working? Is there a crash?